# Java Class Name As Variable

Tags: java, pointers

```
package OOP_in_java;

public class Number {

public static int numberAdd(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}

public static int numberMult(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 * number2;
}

}
//Please uncomment anyone of commented code for the program to work.
class custom_class {
//static Number n;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Number n = new Number();
    System.out.println(n.numberMult(10, 10));
}

}
```

Can anyone explain the difference between the commented code difference

```
static Number n;
```

Vs

```
Number n = new Number();
```

They both do the same job so Why one would use above other?

Comment: They don't both do the same job!  Look again.  (And Java is different from C++, if you're used to that language.)

Comment: (I looked again myself and I noticed the example is pulling a "cheat" on you.  Try to find the cheat.)

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: They only seem to do the same job because you are calling static methods, instead of instance methods, and calling static methods on a variable works, but is a bit of an anti-pattern. The better form is to use `Number.numberMult(10, 10)`. If these had been instance methods, one would have worked and the other would have thrown a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static Number n;
```

creates a static variable in the class `custom_class` that can be accessed by other methods in that class. You currently don't have any other methods so it's not relevant to you. When would this be used? Perhaps you have a variable `mySpecialNumber` that you will use throughout the class. You can have different methods that use it. One method may multiple the parameter with it. Another method may add the parameter to it. This is going to be a global variable that is accessible throughout the class.

Since it is static, you do not need to instantiate the class in order to use it. It is a variable that stands alone. You do not need to create an object of the class in order to use it. In your case, you can use `n` without creating an instance of the `Number` class. This might provide more flexibility. However, it is less secure and can cause data breaches.

```
Number n = new Number();
```

creates an instance variable of the `Number` object during runtime. It is only accessible within the `main` method. If you had other methods in this class, other methods would not be able to access the value of `n`. Once a variable is declared inside a method, it has a local scope to that variable. Only lines of code in the same method can refer to it. Your main method could as users for their age and store it in a local variable in the main method.

With this methodology, you are instantiating the Number class. This line automatically calls the constructor of the Number class and creates an object of type Number which gets assigned to `n`. In your code you did not specify a constructor so the default constructor would be used. Any changes made to `n` only effect the current runtime. They do not transmit to future runs of the program. The object is created in the main method and therefore only accessible in the main method.

Comment: Can you give  a reason of when to choose what.

Comment: @MustafaHK `when to choose what` There's a second trick here.  You need to think about it carefully on your own, I'm guessing this is the whole point of your homework.

Answer (score 1):

They don't do the same thing.

`static Number n;` declares a **static** variable, but never instantiates it.  `n` is `null`.

`Number n = new Number();` declares a **local** variable `n` and gives it an actual value.

Comment: So does it matter?And if yes then please elaborate it with real case scenario.

Comment: @MustafaHKOf course it matters whether a variable has a value or is null. Your request for a 'real case scenario' is unreasonable.